Flutter Camera Exif orientation is always 0 on my phone
I'm using the Camera package for flutter.
My client has a Samsung S53 phone and when it take a picture in portrait mode, the image is rotated by 90°. I tried on my Oppo A73, but no matter the orientation of my device when I take the picture, the exif orientation always returns 0 (portrait) so I don't know whether or not the image is rotated and if I have to apply any rotation. Is this a bug with the camera plugin or something Android related? Even the width and height are always the same, so I can't understand if the phone was in portrait or landscape mode.
This is the code:
import 'package:fatamtam/presentation/utils/scaffold_messenger_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class TakePicturePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePicturePage({
    super.key,
  });

  static String routePath = '/take-picture';

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePicturePage> {
  CameraController? _controller;
  Future<void>? _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeCamera();
  }

  void initializeCamera() async {
    var permissionResult = await Permission.camera.request();
    if(permissionResult.isDenied || permissionResult.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      if(mounted) {
        showScaffoldMessenger(context,
            permissionResult.isPermanentlyDenied ? "Il permesso è stato permanentemente negato. Abilitalo dalle impostazioni del tuo telefono." : "È necessario fornire i permessi per accedere alla fotocamera.");
        context.pop(null);
      }
      return;
    }

    final cameras = await availableCameras();

    _controller = CameraController(cameras.first, ResolutionPreset.high,
        enableAudio: false);
    print(_controller);
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller?.initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scatta immagine')),
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              _controller != null) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            final scale = 1 /
                (_controller!.value.aspectRatio *
                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio);
            return Transform.scale(
              scale: scale,
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: CameraPreview(_controller!),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller?.takePicture();

            if (!context.mounted) return;

            fixImageRotation(image?.path);

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            context.pop(image?.path);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }

  void fixImageRotation(String? path) async {

  }
}

This is what I tried to read the exif data. Image Orientation is always 0 on my phone.
Any suggestion?
    final bytes = await File(imagePath).readAsBytes();
    final data = await readExifFromBytes(bytes);
    print(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
    print(await getApplicationCacheDirectory());
    if (data.isEmpty || !data.containsKey('Image Orientation')) {
      return imagePath;
    }

    img.Image? image = img.decodeImage(bytes);
    if (image == null) return imagePath;

